# Getting user input into standalone Google Apps Script code

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I run a website where contributors write questions for users. As part of the quality assurance process, reviewers complete a pre-formatted Google Sheet. To streamline the process, I am trying to create a standalone script that reviewers can run from Google Drive. This script will ask the reviewer to submit the URL of the questions they are reviewing. The app will then process this URL, send a request to the site (which will return the relevant metadata), copy and rename a template Google Sheet and auto-populate several of the fields.

However, I am struggling to work out how to get the user input. I think the problem is that the getUi class does not work for Drive but the script cannot call `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` from this context. How else can I get user input into this script?

Comment: you could make it a web app with basic html input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getUi()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getui) and the rest of [UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) classes in Apps Script are only available to be used if the script is a [container bounded script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) and therefore these features will not work with your standalone script.

Alternatively you can use any of these workarounds:

- create an [Apps Script web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) with an HTML file including a simple form where they can add the URL.
- Create an [Add-On](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview) for Google Sheets or Drive that will open a sidebar menu in each user's Google Drive (or Sheets depending on what you want) where they can submit whatever information you want.